# Chinese open bracket with space - single char

Tags: chinese-locale

Im working regexes over chinese language I noticed there is a bracket with space Chinese char
'）' notice this isn't a ')'+whitespace (one delete stroke will delete it).
What is the opening space+'(' single char ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> （ ） (U+FF08 fullwidth left parenthesis), (U+FF09 fullwidth right parenthesis) are parentheses (round brackets).

— [Chinese punctuation (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_punctuation)

As one might expect, the opening fullwidth parenthesis is the character right before the closing one in the Unicode table.

Many of the Western punctuation marks have made their way into modern Chinese writing. They have a lot of space around them to make them as wide as regular characters, which are all the same size. Kind of how the « i » has to be very wide in a monospace font.